# How to escape @ symbol in enviroment file?

Tags: proxy

I have my `/etc/environment` file set up with proxy settings. It looks like this -

```
http_proxy="http://userName:password@proxy:port/"
https_prxoxy="http://userName:password@proxy:port/"
```

The password contains an `@` symbol which somehow seems to be conflicting with the latter `@` symbol because of which I am not able to connect to the network. How do I escape the `@` symbol in the password?

Comment: Have you tried changing the double quotes to single ones? Or am I misunderstanding? Another option might be adding a backslash (`\\`) before the first @ character. If that doesn't work take a look here; http://serverfault.com/questions/506053/how-does-one-properly-escape-a-leading-character-in-linux-etc-environment

Comment: changing to single quote did not work!

Comment: @Seth: The backslash will work at shell level, not at connection level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say that the password is `123@456`. In that case, the correct wat to escape the `@` symbol is this:

```
http_proxy="http://userName:123%40456@proxy:port/"
https_prxoxy=same_as_above
```

I've only replaced the `@` with its ASCII hexadecimal representation (`%40`)